# xamarin android ftp error

Tags: c#, android, ftp, xamarin

I want to download a file with ftp (in an xamarin Android app).

Here is code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://addres.com/file.txt");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
keys_from_server = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

I have error in this part of code, I can't debug the program.

Maybe I must check some permissions in the Android manifest file?
I have checked: internet, internal storage.

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Is there an error message?

Comment: i have some error in xamarin studio... i cant debug app... emulator is starting very long time (up to 2 hours) and i dont have time to wait...

Comment: Oh, i forgot! This code works on visual studio 2013 (in *.exe application)

Comment: What error are you getting? I cleaned up the question a bit.

Comment: 1. I cant debug app, so i cant see error message
2. This code dont works in xamarin android, but works in xisual studio in windows app
3. I dont know is code good... I dont know what permissions I must check to connect to ftp via internet...

Answer (score 0):

i think do you have to check manifest permissions like read and write to external storage please do try it. and also check that which is a file format to incoming file and read to stream for that appropriate files and display it.
i hope that it will work.